# How to execute command from C program

Tags: c, bash

What is the best way to execute command such as 'trap -p' etc directly from program written in ANSI C? 
I tried:

```
system("bash");
system("trap -p");
```

But when I add system("bash") program dissappears. How to prevent it from dissapering or what is the better way to execute such commands?

EDIT:

Thank you all for helping me.

More details about what I intended to achieve:
I want to be able to:
-add new traps inside my program ( traps working only in my program )
-display currently set traps ( again, traps in my program )

Is that possible to achive in relatively easy way?

Comment: What happens if you run it without `system("bash");`?

Comment: And what do you mean "disappears" ?

Comment: trap: Illegal option -p

Comment: I mean that what I wanted to achieve is to display traps list from "trap -p" , but what it actually does is moving me to bash, my program is suspended I suppose.

Comment: `system("bash");` opens a new shell, which you send no commands to...

Comment: How to execute trap -p from C then? system("trap -p"), gives an error becouse it runs in sh, not bash.

Comment: Why would you want to check how many traps are in a shell you aren't using?

Comment: I want to check what traps are defined in the script that I am using. Doing system("bash") was a blind shoot.

Comment: Yeah that won't work...

Comment: Please explain what exactly you want to achieve. It looks that you don't understand some basic things about processes and signals. So **edit your question** to improve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sup>I am guessing you are on Linux or some other POSIX system</sup>

You should get a better picture of Linux programming by reading [Advanced Linux Programming](http://www.makelinux.net/alp/). It looks like you are misunderstanding [processes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_%28computing%29) and [signals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_signal).

You cannot catch a signal inside the process running your C program from some shell (either your parent shell, or any child shell started with [system(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/system.3.html). So the output of `trap -p` from any shell is not relevant to your program (but to the shell running it). Hence even using [popen(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/popen.3.html) like  `FILE*fp = popen("trap -p", "r");` (or `popen("bash -i -c 'trap -p'", "r")`....) then reading from `fp` (and at last `pclose`-ing it) is useless.

If you want to handle signals inside your C program, read first *carefully* [signal(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html); then read POSIX [signal.h](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/signal.h.html) documentation (notice `sig_atomic_t`); read also [sigaction(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigaction.2.html), [fork(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html), [execve(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html)

> I want to be able to: *add new traps inside my program*

This has no meaning for C programs running on Linux or POSIX. A C program can handle (with great care and caution!) some [signals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_signal), which are *not* traps.

> [I want to:]  *display currently set traps*

Again, "trap" has no sense inside a C or C++ program, but [signals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_signal) do. You don't really need to display the currently set signal handlers, because you have set them before. And [sigaction(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigaction.2.html) accepts a third *oldact* pointer to hold the *previous* signal action.

*Processor* [traps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trap_%28computing%29) (which are only handled by kernel code, not by application code) are *remotely* and *indirectly* related to *signals*. For example, a [page fault](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_fault) (for implementation of [virtual memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory)) is often handled by the kernel to fill the [page cache](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_cache) with a page from disk (file or swap zone) but may translate to a `SIGSEGV` signal (for [segmentation fault](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segmentation_fault)) sent to the process, which often terminates with a [core dump](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Core_dump).

If you install some signal handler in your C program, be sure to understand what are *async-signal-safe functions* (the only ones you are allowed to call from a signal handler; in particular calling `fprintf` or `malloc` -even indirectly- is forbidden, so is [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)). A useful way of handling a signal is to declare some `volatile sig_atomic_t` variables and set them inside signal handlers (and test and reset them *outside*, e.g. in your event loop).

The shell `trap` [builtin](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bourne-Shell-Builtins.html) is used to manage *some* [signals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_signal) (and also exit and error conditions). To manage signals in C, use [sigaction(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigaction.2.html). To run something at [exit(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/exit.3.html) time, use [atexit(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/atexit.3.html). To handle error conditions, be sure to test every individual [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html) and most library functions (like [scanf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html) or [malloc(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/malloc.3.html) etc etc ..., see [intro(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/intro.3.html)), using [errno(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/errno.3.html)

Answer (score 2):

> But when I add system("bash") program dissappears

Yes, bash is now running and your C program is waiting for it to terminate. It seems to have disappeared because you would be seeing a new shell running in your terminal. Try typing `exit` and your C program will continue. You can confirm this by adding a print statement after `system("bash");`.

You can get `trap -p` to produce output by specifying the `-i` option to bash, which makes it an interactive shell:

```
system("bash -i -c 'trap -p'");
```

From this it would seem that `trap` requires a tty, which non-interactive bash doesn't have.

Or you could put the trap command in a script and run it like this:

```
system("bash script.sh");
```

The contents of `script.sh`:

```
echo Before setting trap...
trap -p
trap somecmd SIGINT
echo After setting a trap...
trap -p
```

In the output you should see that initially there were no traps set (assuming that none were inherited from the shell that ran your C program), and then `trap` should show the newly created trap.

Comment: That is correct, however when I type exit then what's the point of running bash? I want it to print list from "trap -p" first. And I want this to be done automaticly, no interact from user.

Comment: @br33f: Well, it's your code that runs a pointless bash and you said that the program "disappears", so I thought that might be your difficulty. Anyway, I have updated my answer with a possible solution.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of running an interactive `bash`, it seems that you are looking for a way to run `trap -p` in a noninteractive Bash shell.  Here's how you do that.

```
system("bash -c 'trap -p'");
```

However, your C-level signal handlers will not be visible in the `trap -p` output.  Bash can only know about trap handlers which were defined in Bash; and the shell you are starting will not have any (unless they are inherited from the shell you used to start your C program).

Comment: I was gonna suggest this but it won't help in OP's situation as they are using sh to set the traps.